# How to save "text" from Twitter JSON data to a ACF field?

Tags: wordpress, twitter, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, twitter-oauth

I need help with my code. What it's suppose to do is a user enter the full URL from twitter into a text field ('https://twitter.com/openbayou/status/1487977976033685506') and when the post is saved, it breaks down the url by using `explode` and then gets data from a tweet via Twitter API v2.

My code:

```
$tweet_url_raw = get_field('twitter_url');
$parts = explode('/', $tweet_url_raw);
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/' . $parts[5] . '?expansions=author_id&tweet.fields=created_at&user.fields=username,verified';
$authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . get_field_object('twitter_bearer_token', 'option')['value'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$tweet_data = json_encode($result);
$tweet_data2 = json_decode($tweet_data);
```

The code above does get the data:

```
{"data":{"text":"SEC Super Bowl!!","created_at":"2022-01-31T02:36:09.000Z","author_id":"1471331","id":"1487977976033685506"},"includes":{"users":[{"name":"OpenBayou","verified":false,"id":"1471331","username":"openbayou"}]}}
```

The problem I'm having is when I'm trying to get individual data from the output. I'm trying to update a text field called `tweet` with the text from `text`. I've tried to use `update_field('tweet', $tweet_data2->data, $post_id);` and it was blank. When I use                `update_field('tweet2', $tweet_data2["data"], $post_id);` all it saves is `{`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

Since you omitted the `associative` parameter for `json_decode`, it defaults to `false` so you get an object, not an array. You then need to reference it as such:

```
$tweet_data2 = json_decode($tweet_data);
echo 'Tweet text: ' . $tweet_data2->data->text;
```

If you prefer to work with arrays, simply pass `true` to `json_decode`:

```
$tweet_data2 = json_decode($tweet_data, true);
echo 'Tweet text: ' . $tweet_data2['data']['text'];
```

More info on `json_decode` can be found at the PHP Manual site:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Did that and it didn't work. I passed it through var_dump and this is the output: `object(stdClass)#1411 (2) { ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#1419 (4) { ["author_id"]=> string(7) "1471331" ["text"]=> string(16) "SEC Super Bowl!!" ["created_at"]=> string(24) "2022-01-31T02:36:09.000Z" ["id"]=> string(19) "1487977976033685506" } ["includes"]=> object(stdClass)#1421 (1) { ["users"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1420 (4) { ["id"]=> string(7) "1471331" ["verified"]=> bool(false) ["name"]=> string(9) "OpenBayou" ["username"]=> string(9) "openbayou" } } } } `

Comment: There are some issues here. First, your question says "update a text field called tweet with the text from text", but your example shows you calling `update_field` with the data object, not the text field on the data object (you are trying to stuff an object into your "text" ACF field).  Second, is the code you have included in the question above 100% your running code or did you modify it here to ask the question? Based on the JSON data above, both methods employed in my code work. I believe you need to stop using `$tweet_data2->{'data'}` and replace it with `$tweet_data2->{'data'}->{'text'}`

Comment: or if you want the entire 'data' object in your ACF field then you need to serialise it back to JSON first: `update_field('tweet', json_encode($tweet_data2->data->text), $post_id);`

Comment: I got it working by removing `$tweet_data = json_encode($result);` and using `$arr = json_decode($result, true); update_field('tweet', $arr['data']['text'], $post_id);` Thanks everyone for the help.